# Jackson: serialize / deserialize object with one array field

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have got the following class:

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar[] bars;

    @JsonCreator
    public Foo(Bar[] bars) {
        this.bars = bar;
    }
}
```

I would like the a serialized json  to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "x": 1,
    "b": "b1"
  },
  {
    "x": 2,
    "b": "b2"
  }
]
```

where each element in this array is a `Bar`. I have tried to put `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)` but then the serialized json starts with `[[` which probably makes sense, because the whole object then becomes an array.

Is writing a custom serializer the only approach here?

Comment: This is what your output looks like: `{"bars":[{"x":1,"b":"b1"},{"x":2,"b":"b2"}]}` please clarify what do you want? Or simply return a list of Bar for your given JSON.

Comment: Read the question, I stated what I want. "I would like the a serialized json to look like this:"

Answer (score 1):

Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue` annotation. Since version `2.9` you can annotate field, if you use older version annotate getter method.

```
@JsonValue
private Bar[] bars;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have, for example, a controller method that return the `Bar[]` array and not the Foo object that wraps that array, you will have that response:

```
@GetMapping("test")
public Test[] test() {
   return new Test[] { new Test(), new Test() };
}
```

Response:

```
[
  {
    "x": 1,
    "b": "b1"
  },
  {
    "x": 2,
    "b": "b2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create for your self a  [`customised Serializer`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) that will tell `Jackson` how to serialize your object.

```
public class FooSerializer extends StdSerializer<Foo> {
    public FooSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public FooSerializer(Class<Foo> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartArray();

        for (Bar bar : value.getBars()) {
            if (bar != null) {
                jgen.writeObject(bar);
            }
        }

        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

And on your foo class tell `jackson` to use this serializer

```
@JsonSerialize(using = FooSerializer.class)
public class Foo { ... }
```